pullback function by pushforward measure
I saw few posts on that subject but I still couldn't find an answer. Assume that I have a measure space $(\mathcal{X},\nu)$, where $\nu$ is a measure obtained by a pushforward. Is there a way to reconstruct a function that $\nu$ was pushforwarded to? Namely I'm asking if there is a way to obtain a measure space $(\Omega,\mu)$, and a measurable function $f:\Omega\to\mathcal{X}$ such that $\mu_*f = \nu$? Bascally, I can define an equivalence relation of spaces and functions that gives the same pushforward measure, but can I find a representative? I don't think I can, but I can't think on an example.

Take $\Omega=\mathcal{X},$ $\mu=\nu,$ and $f=\operatorname{id}.$

For probability measures $\nu$ on $\mathbb R$ there is something called the "inverse probability transform" which exhibits $\nu$ as the pushforward of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ by the map $u\mapsto F^{-1}(u)$ where $F$ is the distribution function of $\nu$, that is, $F(t)=\nu((-\infty,t])$, and $F^{-1}$ is the "generalized inverse function" of $F$, namely, $F^{-1}(u) = \inf\{x:F(x)\ge u\}$.
Another map inducing the same $\nu$ is $u\mapsto F^{-1}(1-u)$,
and another is $u\mapsto F^{-1}( (u+a)\bmod 1)$, for arbitrary real $a$, and so on.
There is something called a ``standard probability space'' which generalizes this, in a sense.
